# Puppet: variable value in test file

Tags: puppet, rspec-puppet

I'm writing some tests for puppet and in my init_spec.rb file I want to use a variable that is declared in the default_facts.yml file. How could I import the value of that variable without having to declare it in the init_spec.rb file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you would be able to access that data inside the `RSpec.configuration` object.

Supposing you had a default facts file like this:

```
▶ cat spec/default_facts.yml 
# Use default_module_facts.yml for module specific facts.
#
# Facts specified here will override the values provided by rspec-puppet-facts.
---
concat_basedir: "/tmp"
ipaddress: "172.16.254.254"
is_pe: false
macaddress: "AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA"
```

You could address that data in your tests like this:

```rb
it 'ipaddress default fact' do
  expect(RSpec.configuration.default_facts['ipaddress']).to eq '172.16.254.254'
end
```

(I am assuming of course that your default facts file was set up correctly, e.g. by [PDK](https://puppet.com/docs/pdk/1.x/pdk.html).)

If instead you just want a general way to access the data in any arbitrary YAML file, you can also do this:

```
▶ cat spec/fixtures/mydata.yml 
---
foo: bar
```

Then in your tests you can write:

```rb
require 'yaml'
mydata = YAML.load_file('spec/fixtures/mydata.yml')

describe 'test' do
  it 'foo' do
    expect(mydata['foo']).to eq 'bar'
  end
end
```